# Program stops without running the while loop

Tags: c++, while-loop

My while loop is not working. The code runs correctly on the [Codecademy website](https://www.codecademy.com/courses/learn-c-plus-plus/lessons/cpp-compile-execute/exercises/compile-execute) compiler. I then compile it with Visual Studio, run it from the Command prompt and input a number. The program stops prematurely even if the number is the correct one.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

int main() {

  int answer = 8;
  int guess; 
  int tries;

  std::cout << "I have a number between 1-10.\n";
  std::cout << "Please guess it: ";

  std::cin >> guess;  

   while (guess != 8 && tries < 50) {    
    std::cout << "Wrong guess, try again: ";
    std::cin >> guess;   
    tries++;
  }
   if (guess == 8) {   
    std::cout << "You got it!\n";
  }  
}
```

Comment: The variable tries is not initialized, so you have undefined behavior. One compiler might zero it out, another may not.

Comment: Stepping through the code in a debugger would make it really clear where the problem lies. So would enabling hints and warnings in your compiler, which would tell you you're using an uninitialized variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @rsjaffe and @Ken White have said in the comments, the `tries` variable is unitiailized, meaning that the location in memory that the variable is pointing to is "junk" (left over memory). Try to give it an initial value, like this:

```
int tries = 0;
```

which will instantiate and initialize the `tries` variable.